# Count quadtree quadrants number

Tags: quadtree

I'm using a point quadtree and  i need know how i can **count the number of quadrants**  generated after insert the points on a quadtree?

Answer (score 1):

Either raise a counter in the insert method of the quadtree, or count it afterwards, by iterating through the quad tree.